# Cookies in Firefox

Tags: firefox, cookies

Where does Firefox store cookies and in what format are they stored

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## For Windows

Your cookies are stored in:

- In Firefox 2.x: plain text file (`cookies.txt`) in a unix-format text file (eg LF instead of CRLF for newlines).
- In Firefox 3.0 and up: a binary file representing [**SQLite database** on which you can make queries](http://www.webdevbros.net/2008/07/31/query-your-firefox-cookies-with-sql/) ([**`cookies.sqlite`**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies)).

The file is located under your [profile folder](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=ro&comments_parentId=192052&forumId=1):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxx.default
```

where `xxxx` is some random-appearing alphanumeric string.

You might want to install the Firefox plugin [View Cookies](http://www.bitstorm.org/extensions/view-cookies/) to better manage them.

[image]

## For Linux

Your cookies are stored at:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/cookies.sqlite
```

where `xxxx` is some random-appearing alphanumeric string.

Comment: Tools > Options > Privacy > Show Cookies works just as well without the plugin, IMO.

Comment: In Windows XP, Joe's answer of C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cookies.sqllite is correct, not what you currently have.

Comment: @Thomas: nope, cookies are in your profile folder: http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=ro&comments_parentId=192052&forumId=1

Comment: Ok: to all, I convert this answer in a community-wiki one. Edit away ;)

Comment: What does Sure mean in given image? where value is NO

Comment: @UnKnown "Sure"? Or did you mean "Secure"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie "A secure cookie can only be transmitted over an encrypted connection (i.e. HTTPS)." Those in the picture can be transmitted over http or https, so they are not "secure".

Comment: @VonC yes typo mistake. can you give me a useful link where I can understand about cookies security, I don't know how Cookies works internally/back-end or how it could be hacked if we are using just cookies login system? I'm new to Cookies

Comment: @UnKnown http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies is a good start.

Answer (score 6):

Note that in Firefox 3.5, cookies.sqlite is locked exclusively by Firefox, so you have to make a copy of it before reading.

Also, cookies.sqlite may not be flushed to disk until Firefox exits, so you can't assume that the file on disk contains the cookies you need if Firefox is still running.

Answer (score 2):

On XP, in the Application Data\Mozilla folder in C:\documents and settings.

For example, on my machine this is:

C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\cookies.sqllite

Answer (score 2):

It's stored in `PathFromCSIDL(CSIDL_APPDATA) + "Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\" + [[profiledirectory]] + "\" + "cookies.sqlite"` .  There's also a cookies.txt file, but if will probably be empty.  `PathFromCSIDL` can be implemented relatively easily via the windows API.

If your goal is to access cookies programmatically, you'll probably want to do this rather than hard-coding paths.  Note that `[[profiledirectory]]` varies and there may be more than one profile and thus more than one directory, each profile/directory having its own cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The directory depends on your OS, but they appear to be stored in a SQLite database.