# Programmatically set browser cookie (Firefox)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, sqlite, cookies

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302294/cookies-in-firefox) that Firefox 3.0 and up stores its cookies in an SQLite database.  My question is: can you access this database from other **desktop** programs in such a way that you could add a cookie?

I realize this has security implications.  However, I do not want to read them at all.  I want to be able to set one cookie if possible.  I don't even want to overwrite a cookie.  I just want to add it if it isn't there already.  This is sort of a personal project I'm working on for fun.

This question is mostly language agnostic.  I would prefer a solution in C#, but proof of concept in any language will suffice.

Extra credit: It would be cool to set the same cookie in Internet Explorer, too

Comment: +1 Sounds like an interesting project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For FF3, you can access the cookies.sqlite file with [any SQLite wrapper](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=c%23+sqlite&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) - however, check whether FF is running - it may be write-locking the file (not tested).

The database contains this:

```
TABLE moz_cookies (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT, 
    value TEXT, 
    host TEXT, 
    path TEXT,
    expiry INTEGER, 
    lastAccessed INTEGER, 
    isSecure INTEGER, 
    isHttpOnly INTEGER
)
```

Not sure about the primary key, it looks like it is a unix timestamp of when the cookie was created; expiry and lastAccessed are also unix timestamps, the rest is self-explanatory.

Try an `INSERT INTO moz_cookies` and see if FF becomes immediately aware of the new cookie or if it requires a restart.

Comment: Firefox 3.5 locks the cookie file exclusively, so this won't work any more. It's closed as WONTFIX; see 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=476167

Comment: You can still do this with FF not running (which doesn't sound too useful, I admit).

Comment: That's an acceptable limitation though.  Any program that can use an SQLite wrapper to edit the DB in the first place will have the capability to detect whether FF is running and close it or prompt the user to close it before performing any actions.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is really old, but I had the same problem and never really found a complete sample of code (though the answers on this page pointed me in the right direction).  HTH!

```
public static void ClearFirefoxCookies()
{
    int procCount = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox").Length;
    if (procCount > 0)
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("There are {0} instances of Firefox still running", procCount));

    try
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + GetFirefoxCookiesFileName()))
        { 
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "delete from moz_cookies";
            int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        if (!(ex.ErrorCode == SQLiteErrorCode.Busy || ex.ErrorCode == SQLiteErrorCode.Locked))
            throw new ApplicationException("The Firefox cookies.sqlite file is locked");
    }
}

private static string GetFirefoxCookiesFileName()
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles");
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
        throw new ApplicationException("Firefox profiles folder not found");

    string[] fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "cookies.sqlite", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    if (fileNames.Length != 1 || !System.IO.File.Exists(fileNames[0]))
        throw new ApplicationException("Firefox cookies.sqlite file not found");
    return fileNames[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/overview-summary.html and http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/ . Works with current Firefox 11

```
List<Map<String, String>> getCookies() throws Exception
{
    String appdata = System.getenv("APPDATA");
    File fappdata = new File(appdata);
    Path firefox = fappdata.toPath().resolve("Mozilla").resolve("Firefox");
    File profilesini = firefox.resolve("profiles.ini").toFile();
    Ini ini = new Ini(profilesini);

    //TODO:Detect more profiles than just assume default profile configuration
    Ini.Section section = ini.get("Profile0");
    String profiledir = section.get("Path");

    File cookiesfile = firefox.resolve(profiledir).resolve("cookies.sqlite").toFile();

    String cookiesAdress = cookiesfile.getAbsolutePath();

    Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/"+cookiesAdress);
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();

    String query = "select * from moz_cookies";

    ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(query);
    List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while(rs.next())
    {
        Map<String, String> store = new HashMap<>();
        store.put("id", String.valueOf(rs.getInt("moz_cookies.id")));
        store.put("baseDomain", rs.getString("moz_cookies.baseDomain"));
        store.put("name", rs.getString("moz_cookies.name"));
        store.put("value", rs.getString("moz_cookies.value"));
        store.put("host", rs.getString("moz_cookies.host"));
        store.put("path", rs.getString("moz_cookies.path"));
        store.put("expiry", String.valueOf(rs.getInt("moz_cookies.expiry")));
        store.put("lastAccessed", String.valueOf(rs.getInt("moz_cookies.lastAccessed")));
        store.put("creationTime", String.valueOf(rs.getInt("moz_cookies.creationTime")));
        store.put("isSecure", String.valueOf(rs.getInt("moz_cookies.isSecure")));
        store.put("isHttpOnly", String.valueOf(rs.getInt("moz_cookies.isHttpOnly")));
        result.add(store);
    }
    rs.close();
    sta.close();
    conn.close();


    return result;

}
```

Guys, I use this code for my homebrew scrappers. Don't do evil with Firefox cookies or the Mozilla guys will encrypt them and we will nor be able to do funny and harmless stuff with them

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an SQLite connector and connect to the user's cookie db file.  This is located in their default profile folder and is called cookies.sqlite.  Check out [sqlite-manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) for Firefox.  You can view all the tables that Firefox uses with that.

Edit: Here is a link to a provider: [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: I can recommend System.Data.SQLite.  The documentation isn't great, but the functionality's there.  It's a standard ADO.NET provider, and I just used it on a C# desktop app without problems.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

This is great for dealing with SQLite in .NET