# How to get path of Firefox history.sqlite file programatically?

Tags: c#, sqlite, firefox

The path of firefox history file contain a Profile Number how can i get this number dynamically in C#

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\.default\formhistory.sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read profiles.ini file and catch the default profile

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Firefox
{
    class Reader
    {
        public static string ReadFirefoxProfile()
        {
            string apppath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

            string mozilla = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, "Mozilla");

            bool exist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(mozilla);

            if (exist)
            {

                string firefox = System.IO.Path.Combine(mozilla, "firefox");

                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(firefox))
                {
                    string prof_file = System.IO.Path.Combine(firefox, "profiles.ini");

                    bool file_exist = System.IO.File.Exists(prof_file);

                    if (file_exist)
                    {
                        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(prof_file);

                        string resp = rdr.ReadToEnd();

                        string[] lines = resp.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                        string location = lines.First(x => x.Contains("Path=")).Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

                        string prof_dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(firefox, location);

                        return prof_dir;
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code return xxxxxx.default folder whereas all the necessary files are located in xxxxxx.default-release folder.

Comment: @AmolPawar i answered this 6 years ago.so now it's different i guess.i will take a look later.thanks for the information

Comment: This code uses the first `Path` key in the `profiles.ini` file, on my system there instead seems to be an `[Install<HASH>]` section whose `<HASH>` value corresponds to the section name of the [only] section in the `installs.ini` file (for me all these files are in `~/.mozilla/firefox/`). `default-release` was [introduced in Firefox 67](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1259820). You can view these settings at `about:profiles`. The same path is duplicated under the `[Profile0]` section name, and can be accessed through that as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9862643/2668831).

Answer (score 1):

You can read out the following ini file which contains the profile names of every firefoxprofile:

```
"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello To view History in browser url window
enter ctrl h

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5JoO.png)

enter ctrl shift  j

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCgIh.png)

enter windowRoot.ownerGlobal[0].location.href

copy the url open in the new window enter

if unable to enter windowRoot.. console log is not showing follow below procedures
[In Firefox, console.log is not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633404/in-firefox-console-log-is-not-showing-anything)

[In Firefox, browser console is not showing console log window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77881447/in-firefox-browser-console-is-not-showing-console-log-window)

Go to Url `chrome://browser/content/places/historySidebar.xhtml` in firefox

Answer (score -1):

Click the Windows Start button and type `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` in the Search box at the bottom of the Start menu, without pressing Enter. A list of profiles will appear at the top of the Start menu.
Click on the profile with “default” in the name to open it in a window.

Comment: The OP is asking explicity a programatically way