# In Firefox, browser console is not showing console log window

Tags: logging, firefox, browser, console, window

In Firefox, browser console is not showing console log window

Hello To show firefox browser console log when the console is not showing in console log window please follow the below procedures

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html

```
NB: The Browser Console command line (to execute JavaScript expressions) is disabled by default. To enable it set the devtools.chrome.enabled preference to true in about:config, or set the “Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes” (Firefox 40 and later) option in the developer tool settings.
```

[In Firefox, console.log is not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633404/in-firefox-console-log-is-not-showing-anything)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.