# How to get Username of a client, login to client machine in JS or php?

Tags: php, javascript, macos

We have around 10 iMac's connected to mac mini server. php and Apache enabled on server. I am developing intranet website using php.    My requirement is to get the username of the client connected to the server. $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']  is not working. I don't know why. Please help me out. Is it possible to write JS to find it? It should not ask for user login. It should directly take from client machine login.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean exactly, what is it showing?

Comment: What do you mean client machine login? Do you mean the login to the OS? The browser does not provide access to this information to a webpage by default.

Comment: Yeah, `REMOTE_USER` will return something only in the case that the user authenticated with Apache's Basic Auth. What you will get easily is the client's IP using `REMOTE_ADDR`, maybe you can work with that.

Comment: Do you need the IP address or the actual user's name?

Comment: Look at this question and link in comments of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371608/how-to-get-windows-username-in-firefox. You should be able to end up with some helpful info.

Comment: I once had the same requirement. I ended up with a log on script that would write cookies for internet explorer and firefox (I only had to support those), which contained the username. Obviously, this would only work in an intranet environment.

Comment: Hi Pekka, "is not Working" in the sense it is not displaying in the website which i built.. and you are right $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] i am able to work with. I need to display the username when they open the website. And also use that username for giving permissions to view particular pages and all using the username.

Comment: @neelsg I need Username, using which they connected to server

Comment: I believe the OP is after the equivalent of the way windows implements Single-Sign-On using Kerberos/etc... The problem is, that approach relies on the browser being configured to send the appropriate credentials to a site (eg on by default for intranet sites in IE, needs to be configured in FF/Chrome). I don't know if a Mac equivalent even exists? In my experience so far, Macs don't play well with things like this (joining a domain, enforcing policies, etc)

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` will contain the username used for *HTTP auth*. There is no reasonable way to persuade a browser to tell you what OS user the visitor is logged in as (you might have some luck with a signed Java applet, but I wouldn't bet on it).

Comment: Hi Pekka, "is not Working" in the sense it is not displaying in the website which i built..   and you are right $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] i am able to work with. I need to display the username when they open the website. And also use that username for giving permissions to view particular pages and all using the username.

Comment: @vinod — Try replying to the comment on your question with another comment on the *question*, not one on an answer.

Comment: i dont want the OS user to display, I want the server username loged in  from client machine to the server.

Comment: @vinod — If you want to get the username that they used to log into the website with … then that depends entirely on how you implemented that auth system.

Comment: Is there any quick ref i can go through?

Comment: @vinod — A quick reference to the **unspecified** login system that you wrote/bought/inherited/etc? Maybe. We have no way to tell: You haven't told us what login system you are using.

Comment: we use mac mini lion server in our intranet

Comment: @vinod — That's the hardware and the OS. That isn't the website's login system.

Comment: i am not using website login system, the website should take server user login

Comment: @vinod — What server user? The user isn't logged into the server. They are logged into their system profile (which, as stated in this answer, **you cannot get**). Under that they run a web browser. With that web browser that access the site. They aren't logged into the server. (Unless you are using some sort of directory service to handle logging into the client computers in the first place, but you still can't access that as the browser doesn't expose that information to websites).

Comment: Ok so what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

For an intranet site/app, where you have control over the client machines, you can use some script/application running on system startup which will read the username and store it as a cookie. You can than read that cookie from you web site.

How cookies are stored differs between browser. For example, firefox 3+ uses an sqlite database with a documented format (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302294/cookies-in-firefox) for some more info). You have to make sure, that the browser is not running when accessing the cookies.

Comment: What type of script should i use to store the username in a cookie when user loged in...

Comment: Depends on which browsers you need to support and how they store their cookies. I did this in a windows environment for firefox and internet explorer using a visual basic application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is Single Sign On (SSO). This is most commonly used on windows computers connected to a domain which allows users to authenticate to intranet sites without entering any credentials (eg it uses their domain credentials).

I don't know of a pure mac equivalent. The (most recent) Windows system is called Kerberos and is supported by Firefox on Mac as mentioned here: http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/Security/CGLAUTH/CGLAUTH.html

It's worth noting that this requires the OS, Browser and Website to all work together. Some issues: firefox (even on windows) doesn't send the login details automatically, it requires a config change to include the site you want to authenticate with. The website needs to be able to verify the authenticity of the credentials passed to it which usually means it needs to be able to communicate with the credential authority (Domain controller/RADIUS/X500 server, etc.). The pesmissions mechanism needs to support (and be configured) to allow credential delegation (that is, the client PC is allowed to pass tokens on to the website to prove identity).

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/142220/single-sign-on-for-intranet-with-apache-and-linux-mit-kerberos) was by someone who's managed to get this working on linux so should be a good starting point

Comment: Thanx basic.. can you tell me how?

Comment: Have you looked at the links in my answer? One explains how to configure apache, the other explains how to configure the client... What else do you need ?